# removing parts of two strings of an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I'm trying to remove two parts of two strings of an array which is output from ftp_nlist. I am working with CI. ALSO PLEASE NOTE THE MULTI SELECT LIST IN VIEW ARE BEING WORKED ON AND ARE NOT CORRECT CODE WISE. HOWEVER I THOUGHT I SHOULD DISCLOSE THE OTHER SELECT LISTS WHICH SHOWS THE COMPLETE VIEW FILE.

```
    { ["parent_directory_one/child_directory_one"]=> int(0) ["parent_directory_one/child_directory_two"]=> int(1) }
```

how to change the above to the following:

```
    { ["child_directory_one"]=> int(0) ["child_directory_two"]=> int(1) }
```

then how to change this as follows:

```
    { ["parent_directory_one/child_directory_one/child_files_one"]=> int(0) ["parent_directory_two/child_directory_two/child_files_two"]=> int(1) }
```

to the this:

```
      { ["child_files_one"]=> int(0) ["child_files_two"]=> int(1) }
   //controller//
```

ok here's some examples of what I tried and the view files are under construction:

```
    //read default remote
    $glue = '/'; $strs = ''; $root_piece_rm = ltrim($strs, './'); 

    $list_rm = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$root_piece_rm);

    $list_rm = array_flip($list_rm);

    $data['list_rm'] = $list_rm;
    //end read default remote


    if($rm_targets):

    $glue = '/'; $list_sub_rm = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$rm_targets);

    foreach($list_sub_rm as $keys):

        $list_sub_rm  = ltrim($keys,$rm_targets.$glue);

    $data['list_sub_rm'] = var_dump(array($list_sub_rm));

    endforeach;

    endif;
```

However the following code for the sub directories is the problem and I think ltrim isn't going to work. However the var_dump is outputting the strings trimmed according to the pattern which is $rm_targets.$glue that needs to be removed only showing the sub-directories.

```
    //CONTROLLER//
    $rm_targets = $this->input->post('pt_rm_dirs',TRUE);

if($rm_targets):

$glue = '/'; $list_sub_rm = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$rm_targets);

$list_sub_rm = array_flip($list_sub_rm);

$list_sub_rm = array_keys($list_sub_rm);

foreach($list_sub_rm  as $index):

$eraser = ltrim($index,$rm_targets.$glue);

endforeach;

$data['list_sub_rm'] = $list_sub_rm;

endif;
```

Again essentially I need to remove the parent directories from the following strings of an array { ["jm_gallery/new_test_origs"]=> int(0) ["jm_gallery/test_thumbs"]=> int(1) }

I'm not sure how the view or controller need to be setup at the moment.

The output I get from var_dump below is what I need to show in the multi select list. It is essentially the sub directories but the forward slash and parent removed. I haven't had difficulty with such a scenario until I started working with ftp_nlist and it is extremely disturbing.

```
    //CONTROLLER//
if($rm_targets):

$glue = '/'; $list_sub_rm = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$rm_targets);

foreach($list_sub_rm as $keys):

    $list_sub_rm  = ltrim($keys,$rm_targets.$glue);

$data['list_sub_rm'] = var_dump(array($list_sub_rm));

endforeach;

endif;
```

here's the view file which under construction I want to note again so the loops are not yet correct:

```
    //VIEW//
    <?php if(!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

    <?php echo form_open('test_sftp/test_function')?>

    <select name="pt_rm_dirs" multiple size="10">
    <option value="select one"<?php echo set_select('pt_rm_dirs', 'select_one');?>   >select&nbsp;one</option>
    <?php foreach($list_rm as $folder_rm_dirs => $contents_rm_dirs):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $folder_rm_dirs?>"<?php echo set_select('pt_rm_dirs', '$folder_rm_dirs');?> ><?php echo $folder_rm_dirs?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php unset($contents_rm_dirs);?>
```

Step 2:

Specify new names for remote directories selected:

```
    <select name="ct_rm_subdirs" multiple size="10">
    <option value="select one"<?php echo set_select('ct_rm_subdirs', 'select_one');?> >select&nbsp;one</option>
    <?php foreach($list_sub_rm as $sub_folder_rm):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $sub_folder_rm?>"<?php echo set_select('ct_rm_subdirs', '$sub_folder_rm');?> ><?php echo $sub_folder_rm?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php unset($sub_contents_rm);?>
    </select>

    <select name="rm_sub_dirs_files" multiple size="15">
    <option value="select one"<?php echo set_select('rm_sub_dirs_files', 'select_one');?> >select&nbsp;one</option>
    <?php foreach($list_sub_rm as $sub_folder_rm => $sub_contents_rm):?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $sub_folder_rm?>">
    <?php foreach($sub_contents_rm as $files):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $files?>"<?php echo set_select('rm_sub_dirs_files', '$files');?> ><?php echo $files?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php unset($sub_contents_rm);?>
    <?php unset($files);?>
    </optgroup>
    </select> 
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>
    <?php echo form_close()?>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

UPDATE: when I var_dump the code below the strings are changed as I need them but why can't I echo them via the View? I tried converting the strings to an array which became problematic.

```
if($rm_targets):

$glue = '/'; 

$list_sub_rm = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$rm_targets);

foreach($list_sub_rm as $keys):

$list_sub_rm = ltrim($keys,$rm_targets.$glue);

$data['list_sub_rm'] = var_dump($list_sub_rm);

    endforeach;

endif;
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!! 
Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please indent your code properly, and leave empty lines only when necessary.

Comment: sorry thumbmaster. Any other advice that's relevant to the problem I had described lol :)

Comment: You shouldn't be using the so called "leetspeak" here since it makes you look silly.

Comment: do you any advice relevant to the issue I had described? :)

Comment: Hm, I'm having trouble deducing what you want to do from that wall-of-fluffy-text, but doesn't `basename` just do what you want?

Comment: Hi wrikken thanks so much for the reply!! :) Um what I need to do is change the following: { ["jm_gallery/new_test_origs"]=> int(0) ["jm_gallery/test_thumbs"]=> int(1) } to this: { ["new_test_origs"]=> int(0) ["test_thumbs"]=> int(1) }

Comment: The problem is with ftp_nlist and how it outputting the directory information. I am simply outputting first directories in one multi select list. Then outputting sub directories in second multi select list. Then outputting files of sub directories in third multi select list. The problem is for example: ftp_nlist outputs directories as the following: ./jm_gallery then ./sasha's_gallery which are the parent directories at the moment. I corrected this problem but now the sub directories are beign shown again the wrong way and I am now stuck on how to correct problem.

Comment: So another example how to change jm_gallery/test_thumbs and jm_gallery/origs to test_thumbs and origs. Because after the forward slash is the sub directories which only needs to show in the multi select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the filenames are the keys in your array which kind of threw me.

```
foreach ( $list_sub_rm as $key => $value ) {
    $key = preg_replace("#.*/([^/]*)$#", "$1", $key);
    $newArray[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi SpacedMonkey SORRY FOR LATE RESPONSE!!! First I want to say thank you SO SO much for your help. For some reason the code yields a PHP warning error yet it should be working. The warning is 'NO ENDING DELIMITER . FOUND.' I found a post on here that said if you're working within windows environment on the host you need to use preg_quote with preg_replace. So I am not sure though what to do...Does this make sense????

Comment: This is what I have: 
 if($rm_targets):

 $glue = '/'; 
 
 $list_sub_rm = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$rm_targets);

 foreach($list_sub_rm as $key => $value):

      $key = preg_replace(".*/([^/]*)$", "$1", $key);

      $newArray[$key] = $value;
  
 $data['list_sub_rm'] = $value;

      endforeach;

 endif;

Comment: Looks like I didn't delimit my regex properly, try this and I'll edit the post "#.*/([^/]*)$#"

Comment: Hi SpacedMonkey! Sorry the response lag, been having issues with pecl extension. Going to post new question. I resolved the error by encapsulating with '/'. So for example : preg_replace("/.*/([^/]*)$/", "$1", $key); However it didn't have an affect on output and not sure why. Although I decided to use str_replace since it requires less cpu usage for the pattern since the pattern isn't yet complex relatively speaking. I am going to edit my post with the prototype controller and view.